# ping-pong sdl game racket moving

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been trying to make a simple ping-pong game by sdl libraries and now I'm facing a problem!
The game has 2 players, one racket moves by up and down keys, and the other moves by s and w keys.
The problem is e.g. I use up key, both rackets move, and I don't know where the problem is.Considering this rule that both players must be able to move their rackets at the same time.
I compile this code on Ubuntu.
It will be perfect if anyone helps me!
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1200, 800 ,32, 0);

        int i=0,j = 0;
         while(true)
        {
        boxRGBA(screen, 1000, 200+j, 1050, 350+j, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_Event event;
                if(!SDL_PollEvent(&event));
                {
                        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                                return 0;
                        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
              {
                                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP)
                                        j += -5;
                                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN)
                                        j += 5;
                        }
                }

 boxRGBA(screen, 1000, 200+j, 1050, 350+j, 255, 50, 0, 255);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
        SDL_Delay(20);

boxRGBA(screen, 100, 200+j, 50, 350+j, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_Event event2;
if(!SDL_PollEvent(&event2));
                {
                        if(event2.type == SDL_QUIT)
                                return 0;
                        if(event2.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
              {
                                if(event2.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w)
                                        j += -5;
                                if(event2.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_s)
                                        j += 5;
                        }
                }
boxRGBA(screen, 100, 200+j, 50, 350+j, 0,0, 255, 255);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
        SDL_Delay(20);
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   SDL_Delay(2000);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The game has 2 players, but you are using `j` as your variable in both events, is that right? Also, `i` is not being used anywhere.

Comment: yet another "copy/paste" bug creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bracket locations are a pet-peeve of mine.  However, that may have been modified when porting to SO.

You initialized integers i and j, but only variable j has been used.